# How to split all element li to show 10 after click next hide prev 10 and show new jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi all i work with quiz module,

So the issues are, I have dynamically generated data from an array, this is the data i present to the view, this is working good.

I have left tabs, which are built and depends on the length of the questions.

So I need to show in the page first 10 tabs with questions, these are done.

When I press the button **Next question** it's going to next question, but in case if questions more the 10, it's not to change view to **next 10**, in case if I change view manually use **button ">"** it's showing new view, but when i press button **Next question** it's starting from the beginning =(

with this function i sort the `li` element in page:

```
function sortTabs() {
    var $lis = $("#left-tabs li").hide();
    $lis.slice(0, 10).show();
    var size_li = $lis.length;
    var x = 10,
        start = 0;
    console.log(start, x , size_li)
    $('.nex-ten').click(function () {
        if (start + x < size_li) {
            $lis.slice(start, start + x).hide();
            start += x;
            $lis.slice(start, start + x).show();
        }
    });
    $('.prev-ten').click(function () {
        if (start - x >= 0) {
            $lis.slice(start, start + x).hide();
            start -= x;
            $lis.slice(start, start + x).show();
        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of building such a **complex view** and then working with it. You can play with data. Since you are showing only 10 data at a time. You can just build only 10 rows at a time. It will optimize your UI too. Else system dies. Here are some sample methods. You can optimize it accordingly.

Find the update code pen:

https://codepen.io/deepakshrma/pen/jOPWbKW

**Smaple:**

```
const onNext = () => {
      pageInfo.curr = pageInfo.curr + 1;
      if (pageInfo.curr >= pageInfo.limit) {
        pageInfo.page = pageInfo.page + 1;
        pageInfo.curr = pageInfo.curr - 10;
        if (pageInfo.page > PAGE_COUNT) {
          pageInfo.page = 0;
          pageInfo.curr = 0;
        }
      }
      console.log(pageInfo);
    };
```

**// app.js**

```js
var allQuestions = [
  {
    question:
      'Who said, "My real father lost his head at Kings Landing. I made a choice, and I chose wrong."',
    choices: [
      "Robb Stark",
      "Jon Snow",
      "Theon Greyjoy",
      "Arya Stark",
      "Arya Stark",
      "Arya Stark",
      "Arya Stark"
    ],
    answer: "Jon Snow",
    image: "https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_mountains.jpg"
  },
  {
    question: "What does Valar Morghulis mean?",
    choices: [
      "All men must die",
      "What is dead may never die",
      "Never say never",
      "All men must first live",
      "Robb Stark",
      "Jon Snow",
      "Theon Greyjoy"
    ],
    answer: "All men must die",
    image:
      "https://images.pexels.com/photos/459225/pexels-photo-459225.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500"
  },
  {
    question:
      "Which GOT character played Hermoine Granger's mom in Harry Potter?",
    choices: ["Melisandre", "Alerie Tyrell"],
    answer: "Melisandre",
    image:
      "https://media.gettyimages.com/photos/beautiful-book-picture-id865109088?s=612x612"
  },
  {
    question:
      'Who said, "You knelt as boys, now rise as men of the Nights Watch."?',
    choices: [
      "Maester Aemon",
      "Eddard Stark",
      "Jeor Mormont",
      "Alliser Thorne"
    ],
    answer: "Maester Aemon",
    image: "https://tinypng.com/images/social/website.jpg"
  },
  {
    question: "What is Daenerys Targaryens brothers name?",
    choices: ["Varys", "Viserys", "Aerys", "Aegon"],
    answer: 1,
    image: ""
  },
  {
    question: "What is a big fear of the Dothraki?",
    choices: ["Fire", "Salt water", "Heavy stone", "Crows"],
    answer: 1,
    image: ""
  },
  {
    question: "How many swords make up the Iron Throne?",
    choices: ["500", "1000", "2000", "5000"],
    answer: 1,
    image: ""
  },
  {
    question: "What were Jon Arryn's final words?",
    choices: [
      "Winter is coming",
      "Beware of the white walkers",
      "The seed is strong",
      "Beware the dwarf"
    ],
    answer: 2,
    image: ""
  },
  {
    question: "Who built the Iron Throne?",
    choices: [
      "Aerys the Mad King",
      "Aegon The Unlikely",
      "Aegon the Conqueror",
      "Aegon the Destroyer"
    ],
    answer: 2,
    image: ""
  },
  {
    question: "Which knight takes a lance through the neck while jousting?",
    choices: [
      "Ser Hugh of the Vale",
      "Ser Barristan Selmy",
      "Ser Ilyn Payne",
      "Ser Gregor Clegane"
    ],
    answer: 0,
    image: ""
  },
  {
    question: "What does Valar Morghulis mean?",
    choices: [
      "All men must die",
      "What is dead may never die",
      "Never say never",
      "All men must first live",
      "Robb Stark",
      "Jon Snow",
      "Theon Greyjoy"
    ],
    answer: "All men must die",
    image:
      "https://images.pexels.com/photos/459225/pexels-photo-459225.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500"
  },
  {
    question:
      "Which GOT character played Hermoine Granger's mom in Harry Potter?",
    choices: ["Melisandre", "Alerie Tyrell"],
    answer: "Melisandre",
    image:
      "https://media.gettyimages.com/photos/beautiful-book-picture-id865109088?s=612x612"
  },
  {
    question:
      'Who said, "You knelt as boys, now rise as men of the Nights Watch."?',
    choices: [
      "Maester Aemon",
      "Eddard Stark",
      "Jeor Mormont",
      "Alliser Thorne"
    ],
    answer: "Maester Aemon",
    image: "https://tinypng.com/images/social/website.jpg"
  },
  {
    question: "What does Valar Morghulis mean?",
    choices: [
      "All men must die",
      "What is dead may never die",
      "Never say never",
      "All men must first live",
      "Robb Stark",
      "Jon Snow",
      "Theon Greyjoy"
    ],
    answer: "All men must die",
    image:
      "https://images.pexels.com/photos/459225/pexels-photo-459225.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500"
  },
  {
    question:
      "Which GOT character played Hermoine Granger's mom in Harry Potter?",
    choices: ["Melisandre", "Alerie Tyrell"],
    answer: "Melisandre",
    image:
      "https://media.gettyimages.com/photos/beautiful-book-picture-id865109088?s=612x612"
  },
  {
    question:
      'Who said, "You knelt as boys, now rise as men of the Nights Watch."?',
    choices: [
      "Maester Aemon",
      "Eddard Stark",
      "Jeor Mormont",
      "Alliser Thorne"
    ],
    answer: "Maester Aemon",
    image: "https://tinypng.com/images/social/website.jpg"
  },
  {
    question: "Who built the Iron Throne?",
    choices: [
      "Aerys the Mad King",
      "Aegon The Unlikely",
      "Aegon the Conqueror",
      "Aegon the Destroyer"
    ],
    answer: 2,
    image: ""
  },
  {
    question: "Which knight takes a lance through the neck while jousting?",
    choices: [
      "Ser Hugh of the Vale",
      "Ser Barristan Selmy",
      "Ser Ilyn Payne",
      "Ser Gregor Clegane"
    ],
    answer: 0,
    image: ""
  },
  {
    question: "What does Valar Morghulis mean?",
    choices: [
      "All men must die",
      "What is dead may never die",
      "Never say never",
      "All men must first live",
      "Robb Stark",
      "Jon Snow",
      "Theon Greyjoy"
    ],
    answer: "All men must die",
    image:
      "https://images.pexels.com/photos/459225/pexels-photo-459225.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500"
  },
  {
    question:
      "Which GOT character played Hermoine Granger's mom in Harry Potter?",
    choices: ["Melisandre", "Alerie Tyrell"],
    answer: "Melisandre",
    image:
      "https://media.gettyimages.com/photos/beautiful-book-picture-id865109088?s=612x612"
  },
  {
    question:
      'Who said, "You knelt as boys, now rise as men of the Nights Watch."?',
    choices: [
      "Maester Aemon",
      "Eddard Stark",
      "Jeor Mormont",
      "Alliser Thorne"
    ],
    answer: "Maester Aemon",
    image: "https://tinypng.com/images/social/website.jpg"
  },
  {
    question: "What does Valar Morghulis mean?",
    choices: [
      "All men must die",
      "What is dead may never die",
      "Never say never",
      "All men must first live",
      "Robb Stark",
      "Jon Snow",
      "Theon Greyjoy"
    ],
    answer: "All men must die",
    image:
      "https://images.pexels.com/photos/459225/pexels-photo-459225.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500"
  },
  {
    question:
      "Which GOT character played Hermoine Granger's mom in Harry Potter?",
    choices: ["Melisandre", "Alerie Tyrell"],
    answer: "Melisandre",
    image:
      "https://media.gettyimages.com/photos/beautiful-book-picture-id865109088?s=612x612"
  },
  {
    question:
      'Who said, "You knelt as boys, now rise as men of the Nights Watch."?',
    choices: [
      "Maester Aemon",
      "Eddard Stark",
      "Jeor Mormont",
      "Alliser Thorne"
    ],
    answer: "Maester Aemon",
    image: "https://tinypng.com/images/social/website.jpg"
  },
  {
    question: "Who built the Iron Throne?",
    choices: [
      "Aerys the Mad King",
      "Aegon The Unlikely",
      "Aegon the Conqueror",
      "Aegon the Destroyer"
    ],
    answer: 2,
    image: ""
  },
  {
    question: "Which knight takes a lance through the neck while jousting?",
    choices: [
      "Ser Hugh of the Vale",
      "Ser Barristan Selmy",
      "Ser Ilyn Payne",
      "Ser Gregor Clegane"
    ],
    answer: 0,
    image: ""
  },
  {
    question: "What does Valar Morghulis mean?",
    choices: [
      "All men must die",
      "What is dead may never die",
      "Never say never",
      "All men must first live",
      "Robb Stark",
      "Jon Snow",
      "Theon Greyjoy"
    ],
    answer: "All men must die",
    image:
      "https://images.pexels.com/photos/459225/pexels-photo-459225.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500"
  },
  {
    question:
      "Which GOT character played Hermoine Granger's mom in Harry Potter?",
    choices: ["Melisandre", "Alerie Tyrell"],
    answer: "Melisandre",
    image:
      "https://media.gettyimages.com/photos/beautiful-book-picture-id865109088?s=612x612"
  },
  {
    question:
      'Who said, "You knelt as boys, now rise as men of the Nights Watch."?',
    choices: [
      "Maester Aemon",
      "Eddard Stark",
      "Jeor Mormont",
      "Alliser Thorne"
    ],
    answer: "Maester Aemon",
    image: "https://tinypng.com/images/social/website.jpg"
  },
  {
    question: "What does Valar Morghulis mean?",
    choices: [
      "All men must die",
      "What is dead may never die",
      "Never say never",
      "All men must first live",
      "Robb Stark",
      "Jon Snow",
      "Theon Greyjoy"
    ],
    answer: "All men must die",
    image:
      "https://images.pexels.com/photos/459225/pexels-photo-459225.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500"
  },
  {
    question:
      "Which GOT character played Hermoine Granger's mom in Harry Potter?",
    choices: ["Melisandre", "Alerie Tyrell"],
    answer: "Melisandre",
    image:
      "https://media.gettyimages.com/photos/beautiful-book-picture-id865109088?s=612x612"
  },
  {
    question:
      'Who said, "You knelt as boys, now rise as men of the Nights Watch."?',
    choices: [
      "Maester Aemon",
      "Eddard Stark",
      "Jeor Mormont",
      "Alliser Thorne"
    ],
    answer: "Maester Aemon",
    image: "https://tinypng.com/images/social/website.jpg"
  },
  {
    question: "Who built the Iron Throne?",
    choices: [
      "Aerys the Mad King",
      "Aegon The Unlikely",
      "Aegon the Conqueror",
      "Aegon the Destroyer"
    ],
    answer: 2,
    image: ""
  },
  {
    question: "Which knight takes a lance through the neck while jousting?",
    choices: [
      "Ser Hugh of the Vale",
      "Ser Barristan Selmy",
      "Ser Ilyn Payne",
      "Ser Gregor Clegane"
    ],
    answer: 0,
    image: ""
  },
  {
    question: "What does Valar Morghulis mean?",
    choices: [
      "All men must die",
      "What is dead may never die",
      "Never say never",
      "All men must first live",
      "Robb Stark",
      "Jon Snow",
      "Theon Greyjoy"
    ],
    answer: "All men must die",
    image:
      "https://images.pexels.com/photos/459225/pexels-photo-459225.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500"
  },
  {
    question:
      "Which GOT character played Hermoine Granger's mom in Harry Potter?",
    choices: ["Melisandre", "Alerie Tyrell"],
    answer: "Melisandre",
    image:
      "https://media.gettyimages.com/photos/beautiful-book-picture-id865109088?s=612x612"
  },
  {
    question:
      'Who said, "You knelt as boys, now rise as men of the Nights Watch."?',
    choices: [
      "Maester Aemon",
      "Eddard Stark",
      "Jeor Mormont",
      "Alliser Thorne"
    ],
    answer: "Maester Aemon",
    image: "https://tinypng.com/images/social/website.jpg"
  },
  {
    question: "What does Valar Morghulis mean?",
    choices: [
      "All men must die",
      "What is dead may never die",
      "Never say never",
      "All men must first live",
      "Robb Stark",
      "Jon Snow",
      "Theon Greyjoy"
    ],
    answer: "All men must die",
    image:
      "https://images.pexels.com/photos/459225/pexels-photo-459225.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500"
  },
  {
    question:
      "Which GOT character played Hermoine Granger's mom in Harry Potter?",
    choices: ["Melisandre", "Alerie Tyrell"],
    answer: "Melisandre",
    image:
      "https://media.gettyimages.com/photos/beautiful-book-picture-id865109088?s=612x612"
  },
  {
    question:
      'Who said, "You knelt as boys, now rise as men of the Nights Watch."?',
    choices: [
      "Maester Aemon",
      "Eddard Stark",
      "Jeor Mormont",
      "Alliser Thorne"
    ],
    answer: "Maester Aemon",
    image: "https://tinypng.com/images/social/website.jpg"
  }
];
let pageInfo = {
  curr: 0,
  page: 0,
  limit: 10,
  total: allQuestions.length
};
const PAGE_COUNT = Math.round(pageInfo.total / pageInfo.limit - 1);
const onNext = () => {
  pageInfo.curr = pageInfo.curr + 1;
  if (pageInfo.curr >= pageInfo.limit) {
    pageInfo.page = pageInfo.page + 1;
    pageInfo.curr = pageInfo.curr - 10;
    if (pageInfo.page > PAGE_COUNT) {
      pageInfo.page = 0;
      pageInfo.curr = 0;
    }
  }
  console.log(pageInfo);
};
const onPrev = () => {
  pageInfo.curr = pageInfo.curr - 1;
  if (pageInfo.curr < 0) {
    pageInfo.curr = pageInfo.limit - 1;
    pageInfo.page = pageInfo.page - 1;
    if (pageInfo.page < 0) {
      pageInfo.page = PAGE_COUNT;
    }
  }
  console.log(pageInfo);
};

const onPageNext = () => {
  pageInfo.page = pageInfo.page + 1;
  if (pageInfo.page > PAGE_COUNT) {
    pageInfo.page = 0;
    pageInfo.curr = 0;
  }
  console.log(pageInfo);
};

const onPagePrev = () => {
  pageInfo.page = pageInfo.page - 1;
  if (pageInfo.page < 0) {
    pageInfo.page = PAGE_COUNT;
  }
  console.log(pageInfo);
};
const fetctData = () => {
  const curr = pageInfo.page * pageInfo.limit;
  return allQuestions.slice(curr, curr + 10);
};

onNext();
console.log(pageInfo);

onPrev();
console.log(pageInfo);
onNext();
onNext();
onNext();
onNext();
onNext();
console.log(pageInfo);

onNext();
onNext();
console.log(pageInfo);

onNext();
console.log(pageInfo, fetctData());

onPageNext();

console.log(pageInfo, fetctData());
onPagePrev();
console.log(pageInfo, fetctData());
```

Comment: Oh, your solution is very complicate for me :8

Comment: on next call -> onNext
on prev -> onPrev
on next page -> onPageNext
on prev page -> onPagePrev

and  fetch data and build UI :/ I think this is more simple.. split business logic from UI. Please try

Comment: I am realy beginer, and have no idea how to use your method :(

Comment: Please check now. i have updated code pen. You just need to clean up answer table.